# My file is not working and reading the context from the file in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream, ifstream

I tried to open a certain file and read the content to put it into a string named letters but then every time I typed the file name I keep getting error can't find open the file.

void createTree()
{

```
BTS tree;
string filename;
string letters;
ifstream file;
int input = 0;

cout<<"Enter the file name:  ";     // ask the user to input the file name
cin >>filename; //input the user input into filename

file.open(filename.c_str());
if(file)
{
    cout<<"File is open";
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        cout<< "In the while loop"<<endl;
        getline(file, letters);
        tree.insertWord(letters);
    }
}

else
      cout<<"Error can't open the file"<<endl;
tree.printTree();

file.close();
```

}

Comment: Post all of your actual code, not just a selection of it.

Comment: What's your setup? If you're working inside an IDE, it could be that the executable is running in a different directory than what you think. Also, note that `c_str()` in `file.open(filename.c_str());` is unnecessary, `ifstream` is perfectly aware of `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the `getline` call slightly, see if this works:

```
void createTree()
{
    BTS tree;
    string filename;
    string letters;
    ifstream file;
    int input = 0;

    cout<<"Enter the file name:  ";     // ask the user to input the file name
    cin >>filename; //input the user input into filename

    file.open(filename.c_str());
    if(file)
    {
        cout<<"File is open" << endl;
        ifstream file(filename.c_str());
        char chars[100];

        while (!file.eof()) {
            file.getline(chars, 100);
            tree.insertWord(letters);
            letters = chars;
            cout << letters << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout<<"Error can't open the file"<<endl;
    }
    tree.printTree();

    file.close();
}
```

Comment: It's still not working... I think the problem is that my program can't find the file maybe because of the file format or the location of my file. I will let you know guys if I resolve the problem

Comment: I figured what was wrong! I just forget to type the file format (.txt) when I was entering the file name